# Proving that the language is regular or not

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

We use pumping lemma for regular languages to find a language is regular or not. There is a question in the homework that I don't know how to apply pumping lemma onto the language.

```
L = {a$b: a,b ∈ {0,1}*, number of zeroes in a equals to the number of ones in b}
```

$ is just a constant there to split a and b.

There is also a language such that:

```
L = {ab: a,b ∈ {0,1}*, number of zeroes in a equals to the number of ones in b}
```

I understand that now there is nothing to split a and b and it's not possible to make assumptions about number of zeroes in a and number of ones in b, right? Or am I mistaken?

How do we apply pumping lemma to these languages to prove them regular or not?